# Do the set of solutions of $y'' + y = \cos(t)$ form a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I think the answer is NO, because it's not closed under scalar addition. For example, take two solutions $y_1, y_2$. Then

$$y_1''(t) + y_1(t) = \cos(t) $$

$$y_2''(t) + y_2(t) = \cos(t) $$

But,

$$(y''_1(t)+y_2''(t))+(y_1(t)+y_2(t))=2\cos(t).$$

So it's not closed under addition. Am I correct?

Comment: Even simpler: if it were a vector space, then it would contain $y(t)=0$; but it doesn't.

Comment: Also not closed under multiplication by the scalar  $2$, e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The solutions of a *homogeneous* linear differential equation form a vector space, but not the solutions of an inhomogeneous linear differential equation.